# How to continue JS file after os.system is run in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I need to have the os.system run and then the next line run after.  As it stands now it only runs after i close the terminal window but I want it to all run at the same time.

```
  gameUrl_entry.delete(0, END)
  command="python3 --version"
  os.system("lxterminal -e xvfb-run -a node /var/www/html/scoreboard/node/score/mscl-scrapper/mvcc.js")
  subprocess.run('/var/www/html/scoreboard/kiosk.sh', shell=True, check=True, timeout=10)
```

So basically after mvcc.js is open and doing its work then run the kiosk.sh file.  The mvcc scrapes and the the kiosk displays the info.

Thank you for the help guys

Comment: May I ask why are you running python3 rather than a bash script?

Comment: @user1462442 This is a form that is displayed on a raspberry pi and after the URL field is filled in this runs.